# angularjs - don`t access to my $scope value

Tags: angularjs

I want to use angular-ui to create a dynamic menu
in my LoginCtrl. I call a service to get menu from server to show in dashboard.
here is my code:

in LoginCtrl controller:

```
    UserService.getMenu().then(
    function (result) {
        $scope.menu = result;
        $location.path('/dashboard');

    }, function (status) {
        $scope.msg = "error " + status + " has been occur,please report to admin ";
    }
);
```

in dashboard.html

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">Open only one at a time
  </label>

  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <!--nashta-->
    <accordion-group heading="{{project.name}}" ng-repeat="project in menu.projectName">

      <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <!--bank-->
        <accordion-group heading="{{bank.name}}" ng-repeat="bank in menu.bankingList">

          <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <!--working pack-->
            <accordion-group heading="{{wp.name}}" ng-repeat="wp in menu.workingPackList">

              <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                <!--product pack-->
                <accordion-group heading="{{pr.name}}" ng-repeat="pr in menu.productList">
                </accordion-group>
              </accordion>

            </accordion-group>
          </accordion>

        </accordion-group>
      </accordion>

    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

but I don`t no why it does not work.my menu load from server successfully but in dashboard.html I can not access to $scope.menu.

I was wandering whay it work in another html file 
for example if I copy the above code in login.html, I can access to $scope.menu

[image]

but It does not work in dashboard!!!

my login controller:

```
'use strict';
```

angular.module('mabnaaApp')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {

```
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.user = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    $scope.submit = function (user) {
        if ($scope.loginForm.$valid) {

            UserService.login(user).then(
                function (result) {

                    UserService.getMenu().then(
                        function (result) {
                            $scope.menu = result;
                            $location.path('/dashboard');

                        }, function (status) {
                            $scope.msg = "error " + status + " has been occur,please report to admin ";
                        });

                }, function (reason) {
                    $scope.msg = "username or password is not correct";
                });
            $scope.reset();
        }
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.user = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
    };

    var existy = function (x) {
        return x != '';
    };

    $scope.userExists = function () {
        return  existy($scope.user.username);
    };

    $scope.isLogin = !existy($scope.user.username);
});
```

Comment: I think you are trying to access scope inside the service, which will not accessible there

Comment: Can u confirm controller name and ng-controller value ?

Comment: you assign $scope.menu, and redirecting using $location.path('/dashboard');, which would reload the page and clear the result.

Comment: but I can access  $scope.oneAtATime = true; in dashboard.html

Comment: <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="oneAtATime">Open only one at a time
            </label> this work in dashboard

Comment: what service I have to use instead of $location ? how can I handel it. thx

Comment: Using $location is fine. But the meny should be loaded by the controller associated to the /dashboard url, and be added to the scope of that controller. The way you're doing it here, the menu is added to the scope of the LoginCtrl, and immediately after, you're navigating to a new URL, which thus uses another scope and another controller.

Comment: Declare $scope.menu the same as you did with oneAtAtime. and don't redirect to the view if you are already there. In my opinion this code should go into a resolve method of the $routeProvider. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider